# User validation in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I've been working on a project in Google Sheets for my team! The thing is: I've a sheet inside it and I want only me and 2 other people (they can edit the sheet) to see it, so that anyone entering with a "View-Only" permission would not see it!

***EDIT: Let me explain a little better: I have a project which includes the specific sheet (let me call it Sheet_1) that I want to keep secret.
The project consists in a database for financial status of my team, so it is mandatory that ALL team members may see it. But there's the catch: I don't want EVERYONE in the team to see Sheet_1, I want only a specific group (call it Admins) to be able to see it. I cannot simply hide Sheet_1 because every time the Admins edit it in any way, it becomes visible for everyone again.***

***So let me be clear over who's involved in this
Admins: People (including me) who can see everything and change everything in the project
Non-Admins: People who must view the project in a "View-Only" Mode, and may not see Sheet_1***

I've searched for a little bit and this is the code that I have:

```
    function onOpen() {
  var adminUsers = ['admin@email.com'];


  if (adminUsers.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname').showSheet()
  }

  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname').hideSheet()
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work! It doesn't hide the sheet when the non-Admins view my project, and it also asks for a Google login each time someone opens the project!

So, the code that I'm looking for is something like this:

```
 function onOpen(){
  var admin = [authorized emails that I inputted manually]
  var email = getCurrentUserEmail()

  if(email is in admin){
      show specific sheet
  }

  else{
      don't show specific sheet
  }
```

***EDIT: I see now that maybe what I'm asking is too complicated, so I'd be glad if anyone could give me suggestions!***

Can anyone help me with this? I'll give more detalis if necessary! 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. There's not enough information to answer your question. Please edit your question to include full details about the specific groups of people who access the spreadsheet and their rights, about _how_ the spreadsheet has been shared (with whom, how, what rights, etc), about which (if any) users are required to login to access the spreadsheet, and what you meant by "But this code doesn't stop other people from seeing that sheet". Since your editors can see any hidden sheet and "view-only" users can’t see hidden sheets, why not just hide the sheet anyway?

Comment: Tedinoz, I've changed some details, see if it's clear now

Comment: Just a thought; untested. Have you considered having two spreadsheets. One that contains the data (secure and non-secure); it also includes the view-only sheets. The second spreadsheet is linked to the first for the view-only ranges. Using this approach, someone viewing the second spreadsheet would have no idea of the content of the first.

Comment: After some research, I think that's what I'm going to do! Now what I've to do is think of a way for automaticly fill the second spreadsheet whenever I edit the first one

Comment: _how to update the second spreadsheet whenever I edit the first one_ That is a pretty common problem, and you should find a whole bunch of topics (and answers and workarounds) here on StackOverflow, in Webapps.StackExchange , the Google support pages and on the web generally. Remember "Google is your friend" ;)